# Cypress save value from one function and use it another function

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a function which creates random email address at the Signup page. I want to use the returned random email address in Login Page later. How do I do that? This function to create random email is in Commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generate_random_string', (string_length) => { 
    let random_string = '';
    let random_ascii;
    for(let i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
        random_ascii = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 97);
        random_string += String.fromCharCode(random_ascii) 
    }

    return random_string+ '@hotmail.com'
 
   })
```

In my Signup for new account page, I have used this function as the following, I have the following script in fileA.js

```
 email() {
     return cy.generate_random_string(5).then(random => {
        cy.get('#emailSignup').type(random)
        return cy.wrap(random)
      .as('randomID')
      })
}// this types the email address we generated from the above fn.
```

I want just to just get the randomly generated email to be used for later in other tests. Like example: Assertion for Signin page/ signin as the new user using the email generated. I have the following in fileB.js

```
 assertemailloginpage() {

       cy.get('[data-testid="navigationStack2Route-main"]').contains('randomID')}
```

another option would be just get the value which got generated from commands.js custom commands. I am not sure how to get the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Cypress.env` variable to save a value and then use it globally like this:

```js
cy.generate_random_string(5).then((random) => {
  Cypress.env('randomEmail', random)
  cy.get('#emailSignup').type(Cypress.env('randomEmail'))
})
```

Comment: My goal is to use the variable in assertion like this "        signuplanding.assertemailloginpage().should(Cypress.env('randomEmail'))". I tried contains and should but both fails. "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: I have updated the summary and code

Answer (score 0):

Add a couple of `returns` into `email()`. This gets the value out of the POM method.

```js
email() {
  return cy.generate_random_string(5).then(random => {
    cy.get('#emailSignup').type(random)
    return cy.wrap(random)
  })
}
```

In the test, use `.then()` to access the returned value.

```js
signup.email().then(emailusedsignup => {
  signuplanding.assertemailloginpage().contains(emailusedsignup) 
})
```

Once you have one `.then()` in the chain (in this case `cy.generate_random_string(5).then(random =>`) it pays to use `.then()` further down the chain to make sure there's no asynchronous problems.

Comment: I am getting the following error message. CypressError
cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.

Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.

You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another cy.then().

The value you synchronously returned was: rwkey@hotmail.com

Comment: Ok, that should be fixed with `return cy.wrap(random);`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is email() method has different elements than asserteemailloginpage(). When I run the script, it is looking for elements in () to return the value of the email. I guess I need to separate the code in email() to extract just the value that is being returned.

Comment: I can't really tell what `assertemailloginpage()` is doing, but it looks dodgy - the `return` line then the following `cy.get()` line should be throwing an error or warning.

Comment: This is what I have in assertemailloginpage() " assertemailloginpage() {

               return cy.get('[data-testid="navigationStack2Route-main"]')
    }. I am then verifying  signup.email().then((emailusedsignup)=> {
            signuplanding.assertemailloginpage().contains(emailusedsignup)

        }) // When it is run, first email() is looking for elements in this method.

Comment: yes, i get an error saying "looking for elements in email()" but never found, this time the script is in the landing page.

Comment: Difficult to debug remotely, but if you temporarily comment out `signuplanding.assertemailloginpage().contains(emailusedsignup)` does the error still appear? I checked out the `return cy.wrap(random)` and that looks ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247894/discussion-between-user2744620-and-fody).